# $P$ is midpoint of $BC$, $Q$ is any point on $AB$: find length of $AQ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

> Let $\Delta ABC$ be a right-angled triangle with $\angle ABC$ as the right angle. Let $P$ be the mid point of $BC$ and $Q$ be a point on $AB$. Suppose that the length of $BC$ is $2x$, $\angle ACQ=\alpha$ and $\angle APQ=\beta$. Then, what is the length of $AQ$?

[image]

I tried to use $\angle BCQ$ but ended up with a difficult equation which seems wrong. Any hint on how to approach this?

Comment: Show your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Note: notation is changed to exploit
the usual: $a,\,b,\,c$ denote the side lengths,
and $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma$ as the angles of $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

> Given the right-angled $\triangle ABC$, $\angle BCA=90^\circ$, point
> $P\in AC:\ |AP|=|CP|=\tfrac12b$, point $Q\in BC$, and two angles
> $\angle QAB=\phi, \angle QPB=\theta$, find $|BQ|=q$.

\begin{align} 
\triangle AQC:\quad
a-q&=b\,\tan(\alpha-\phi)
=
\frac{b\,(\tan\alpha-\tan\phi)}{1+\tan\phi\tan\alpha}
=
\frac{b\,(a\cot\phi-b)}{a+b\cot\phi}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
q&=
\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b\cot\phi}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\triangle CPQ:\quad
a-q&=
\tfrac12\,b\tan(\angle CPB-\theta)
=
\frac{\tfrac12\,b\,(\tan\angle CPB-\tan\theta)}{1+\tan\angle CPB\tan\theta}
=
\frac{\tfrac12\,b\,(2a\cot\theta-b)}{2a+b\cot\theta}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

From \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} we have a quadratic equation in $a$:

\begin{align}
k_2\,a^2+k_1\,a+k_0&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
k_2&=4\cot\phi-2\cot\theta
,\quad
k_1=-3b
,\quad
k_0=b^2\,(\cot\phi-2\cot\theta)
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of the solution of \eqref{4}
into \eqref{2} gives the result

\begin{align}
q&=\frac{\tfrac32b}{2\cot\phi-\cot\theta}
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Comment: angleABC =90° not angle ACB

Comment: @mmittal1971: It is noted at the very beginning of the answer, that notation is changed to exploit the usual: $a,\,b,\,c$ denote the side lengths,
and $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma$ as the angles of $\triangle ABC$.
Also, to simplify the train of thoughts,
the right angle is $\angle BCA=\gamma$, that is, the usual $c^2=a^2+b^2$ holds.
Otherwise, the question is the same. 
In terms of the original question, 
the answer would be $|AQ|=\frac{3x}{2\cot\alpha-\cot\beta}$.